# Paypal IPN return INVALID with no data

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, paypal-ipn

I had this question yesterday too but for sandbox but as some person suggested me that sandbox is buggy & I should test with live paypal.

Here is the condition --

I have a Drupal form, where I am collecting some data, I make query from that & send that to paypal with the URL like --

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' .$query;
```

Where result of the query variable carry --

```
cmd=_xclick&business=ctaep.austin%40gmail.com&page_style=Primary&bn=PP-DonationsBF&item_name=Membership¤cy_code=USD&no_shipping=1&tax=0&lc=US&rm=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Fctaep-test.kr001.us%2F%3Fq%3Dpaypal%2Fpayment&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fctaep-test.kr001.us%2F%3Fq%3Duser%2Fregister&uname=Raj_vm&email=rajeevkr.dei%40gmail.com&user_type=General&first_name=Rajeev&last_name=Kumar&comp_name=&address1=sector+27&address2=&city=noida&state=ca&zip=201301&phone=9650361380&mobile=&fax=&amount=0.01&item_number=1
```

After filling the form & submit I got forwarded to paypal, I paid there and then I had to press return button(though I sent return path too with the query),

The status is INVALID as the condition in the function which get called to handle the IPN is always falling in the INVALID condition. Here is the code--

```
function paypal_payment_paypal_ipn_callback(){  
  header("Content-type: text/html");
  header("Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 1975 04:15:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");

  watchdog('paypal', '1');


  // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {        
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
  }

  // post back to PayPal system to validate
  $header = '';
  $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
  $fp =  fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

  if (!$fp) {
    watchdog('paypal', 'HTTP error');
  } 
  else 
  {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    watchdog('paypal-fp-else-', $header . $req);
    dpm($_POST['uname']);
    dpm($_POST['user_type']);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
      watchdog('paypal', '3');
      watchdog('pay_status',$res);      
      if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        watchdog("verified");
        watchdog('paypal', '4');

        //Information about you:
        $receiver_email = $_POST['business'];

        //Information about the transaction:
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

        $user_name = $_POST['uname'];
        $user_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $company_name = $_POST['comp_name'];
        $address_address_line_1 = $_POST['address1'];
        $address_address_line_2 = $_POST['address2'];
        $address_city = $_POST['city'];
        $address_state = $_POST['state'];
        $address_zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $user_phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $user_mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $user_fax = $_POST['fax'];        

        // process payment
        $password = user_password(8);
        $fields = array(
          'name' => $user_name,
          'mail' => $user_email,
          'pass' => $password,
          'status' => 1,
          'init' => $user_email,
          'roles' => array(
            DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => $user_type,),
          'field_first_name' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $first_name))),
          'field_last_name' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $last_name))),
          'field_company_name' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $company_name))),
          'field_address_line_1' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $address_address_line_1))),
          'field_address_line_2' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $address_address_line_2))),
          'field_user_city' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $address_city))),
          'field_user_state' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $address_state))),
          'field_user_zip' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $address_zip))),
          'field_phone_number_' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $user_phone))),
          'field_mobile_number_' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $user_mobile))),
          'field_fax_number_' => array(
              LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
                  array('value' => $user_fax))),
       );
      $account = user_save('', $fields);
      watchdog("user registered");
      }
      elseif (stripos($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        watchdog('Res value--', stripos($res, "INVALID"));
        watchdog('paypal', 'INVALID');
      }
      else{
        watchdog("Not Verified nor Invalid");
      }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
  }
  return 'Transaction Complete';
}
```

I believed, even if status is INVALID I should get the data which I sent in there in return but, when I tried to fetch it by `**$_POST**`(as you can see it before the while loop in else part), I am getting error "Undefined Index".

EDIT---

I tried dumping the $_POST variable & it's just returning me return path in array which is of 14 character.

I don't know what to do..

Can I get any help from anybody about this ?

Comment: print_r($_POST); and look what data it is returning..if this is the method otherwise try using $_GET also

Comment: I tried with dumping $_POST & $_GET. $_POST is returning just the array containing the URL path which is of 14 character...

Comment: have you correctly configured the trackback URL correctly in your Paypal account ?

Comment: @swapnesh - Can you help in this ?

Comment: whatever I can..I will surely assist you :)

Comment: @swapnesh - I didn't do anything with paypal account

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23940/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-rajeevk)

Comment: @swapnesh - Should I try with sandbox once where I have already set the return path in account too ?

Comment: yes first do it under sandbox (weird if someone suggested you not to use that)

Comment: better join me on chat here to make things little fast

Comment: It's more reliable to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of iterating over `$_POST`.

Comment: @Jack - I tried this($raw_post = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $post_array = $this->decodePayPalIPN($raw_post);), for which I am getting this error - Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Comment: @RajeevK That means perhaps you should try `self::decodePayPalIPN($raw_post);`

Comment: @Jack -- I tried $raw_post = file_get_contents("php://input"); & then dump the variable $raw_post, but it was totally blank...

Comment: @RajeevK If that's true, then nothing was posted. If `$_POST` is populated, `'php://input'` must contain data (unless perhaps for file uploads).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23943/discussion-between-rajeevk-and-jack)

Comment: Fix the path first: `ssl://www.paypal.com`. It's not a valid web address.

Answer (score 0):

According to the paragraph "A Sample IPN Message and Response" in https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro you need to POST the *very same string* back that you received. I.e.

> PayPal sends a message, similar to the following one, for a $19.95
>   purchase made by Express Checkout:
>
> mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=20%3A12%3A59+Jan+13%2C+2009+PST&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=Test&mc_fee=0.88&address_country_code=US&address_name=Test+User&notify_version=2.6&custom=&payer_status=verified&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=AtkOfCXbDm2hu0ZELryHFjY-Vb7PAUvS6nMXgysbElEn9v-1XcmSoGtf&payer_email=gpmac_1231902590_per%40paypal.com&txn_id=61E67681CH3238416&payment_type=instant&last_name=User&address_state=CA&receiver_email=gpmac_1231902686_biz%40paypal.com&payment_fee=0.88&receiver_id=S8XGHLYDW9T3S&txn_type=express_checkout&item_name=&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00
>
> Before you can trust the contents of the message, you must first
>   verify that the message came from PayPal. To verify the message, you
>   must send back the contents in the exact order they were received and
>   precede it with the command _notify-validate, as follows:
>
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=19.95&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LPLWNMTBWMFAY&tax=0.00&...&payment_gross=19.95&shipping=0.00

So: Do not alter the data that you received before trying to verify.